# Cannot align text inside a container class properly?

Tags: html, css, alignment, containers

I am trying to align content inside a container div to the left (padding-left:100px ; for example, but couldn't figure out a way to do so. I am guessing that the container class already has a margin and padding? If so how can I override them.

```
  <div class="section1bg">
    <div class="container"> 
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="waldbrandtext1">
           <h2>Waldbrand</h2>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. 
        </div>

        <a data-scroll href="#text2" class="btn btn-warning">Mehr über Waldbrände > </a> 

        <script>
          var scroll = new SmoothScroll('a[href*="#"]', {
            speed: 500,
            speedAsDuration: true
          });
        </script> 

      </div> 
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

That is the HTML. I want the *container* class to be aligned to the left by adding some padding but like I said it does not work.

```
container{  
    width: 100%;
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

That is my CSS. Forget about the code inside the container{} it doesn't work anyway..

So how do I do that?

Comment: First off you have to add a dot. (.Container{}) and also, have you linked ur CSS file to HTML? And to the last question. You’re using width: 100%. Which means you are covering the whole area? I can’t remember 100% sure, but try to decrease the width to the class above and remove 30 px. (It’ll be responsive since you’re placing it inside another div, which I assume you use percentage)

Answer (score 0):

Because you are trying to refer your class as a block (`<container>`) to refer classes you need to put a dot before your class name

```
.container{  
    width: 100%;
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

Comment: Didn't make any difference.